# Power BI custom modal window

Tags: charts, filter, popup, powerbi

I am new to Power BI. I want to create a custom filter popup window in Power BI and a popup window should open separately on click filter icon. Custom filter model window has multiple filter inputs and filters should apply on click `Apply Filter` button. A modal window should close on click cross icon. I would like to know is there a way to create a custom filter modal window in Power BI.

[PowerBI Chart Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zIgh.png)
[PowerBI Filter Modal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvJwR.png)

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this in Power BI. Programming in Power BI allows you to [perform calculations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/data-analysis-expressions-dax-reference). You can [build custom visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/custom-visual-develop-tutorial), but they will appear in your report. You can't show modal windows. It's not that kind of development platform.

You can add your filters as visuals in your report, for example as slicers. You can read more about [how report visuals cross-filter each other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-interactions).

Comment: As stated by @Andrey Nikolov answer, it is not possible to create a model window in Power BI. However, you can create a slicer panel. The slicer panel technique can be found [here](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/create-a-power-bi-slicer-panel/)

Answer (score 0):

The main aim of power Bi is visualization.There is no chance of custom coding except for calculation part. Python and R is helpful in visualization because of their rich libraries. Python will support in even in web url where as R not that much.